# WebApi force action to return xml

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-web-api

I have this action:

```
public IHttpActionResult SearchFor(int aboItemType, DTO.FilterColumns filter)
{
    //Do stuff...
    return Ok<DataSet>(ds);
}
```

My client does:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));

var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(myurl).Result;
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var results = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
}
```

The above scenario works perfectly. However, if I comment the Accept line, the action returns the dataset in json format.

I would like to force this one particular action to always send the result in xml. Is this possible? Maybe with an attribute?

Comment: Well, you're using `PostAsJsonAsync`. Doesn't that mean you're expecting JSON back?

Comment: @DaveVandenEynde - no, it means that they're *sending* JSON. You specify what you're expecting back in both or either of the Accept heading and what method you use to access the `Content` on the response obtained from a particular method.

Comment: No the client posts in json, however the accept header tells the server to return the response in xml.

Comment: Well, if you don't set an `Accept` header, then in the case of `PostAsJsonAsync` no `Accept` header is sent to the server so it's really up to the server to decide what to send back.

Comment: @DaveVandenEynde - correct. So that is why I'm forcing the server to send the response as xml because that's the only format that is applicable for this action.

Comment: I just set up a test client and server. If no Accept header is sent, the server responds with the same media type that was posted. This begs the question: if you're sending JSON, why are you expecting XML as a result? I'd think that client and server either talk JSON or XML for data, based on the technology of the client, and stick to one or the other. That was my initial question, in any case.

Comment: I think json is preferred over xml by default.

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono no, XML is returned by default if no Accept or Content-Type saying otherwise is passed. I tried.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I used `Сonfiguration.Formatters.XmlFormatter`

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
 ...
  return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, Model, Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
}
```

Comment: No. It still returns in json, and I can't use IHttpActionResult as the return type.

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono - you can use `Content()` (instead of `Request.CreateResponse` or your `Ok()`) and with the above parameters, and that does create an `IHttpActionResult`, but still not sure if this is (part of) the right solution.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - works like charm! amend your answer so I can flag it so.

Comment: Man I love the web site.  You guys have no idea how many times my butt is saved because I can access all this knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can do this (in the case you have to pass some http header values):

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    var result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, 
                                        model,
                                        Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);

    result.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

    return ResponseMessage(result);
}
```