# .net web api reponse json wrapped in xml

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

I've created a web api project and made a simple query. Then I converted the data to json and returned the data.
The problem is the data is wrapped by:

```
<string xmls="http/.../"> {json data} </string>
```

The function's definition is:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetAllObjects();
```

and I return with the line

```
return Ok(jsonData);
```

All I need is for the json not to be wrapped by the html tags but still use the IHttpActionResult.

Comment: how do you query your service? second did you make sure to set the contentType or the accept (don't remember which one you should set) attribute of your http query as json

Comment: No.. where do you need to set it? And i use a data reader for the query, then i serialize the data and turn it to json.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22681925/webapi-force-action-to-return-xml)

Comment: any specific reasons?

Comment: Worked thanks!, changed the return line to content instead of ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, apperantly when you return with ok the data you enter is automatically parsed into an xml format, simply use content instead of ok when returning the response.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The only missing piece for me was that the response headers still contained content-type: text/html. Why was that a problem? Because I use the J-SON Formatter Chrome extension, which inspects content-type, and I don't get the pretty formatting I'm used to. I fixed that with a simple custom Formatter that accepts text/html requests and returns application/j-son responses:

```
    public class JsonFormatter : JsonMediaTypeFormatter
    {
           public JsonFormatter() {
            this.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
            this.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                                  }
        public override void SetDefaultContentHeaders(Type type, HttpContentHeaders    headers, MediaTypeHeaderValue mediaType) 
{
            base.SetDefaultContentHeaders(type, headers, mediaType);
            headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
                                                               }
    }
```

and then use this code:

```
 config.Formatters.Add(new JsonFormatter());
```